Is there one regex tool following merely BRE and throwing errors when undefined?
I am reading Software Design for Flexibility (SDF). Exercise 2.10 asks to implement the translator for both BRE and ERE. The book uses grep to test the translated string like (a.c) in ERE to capture something like abc or adc.
I use Arch Linux.

By POSIX specification 9.3.3 BRE Special Characters, \+ is not supported by BRE.
But man grep "Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions" allows \+ for the default option BRE.
The above difference seems to be implied by this Specifications issue (reference of this QA):

The BRE corresponds to the ed or historical grep type

But ed seems to also support \+.

(Edited: This paragraph is wrong since this website doesn't comply to BRE at all when option b is enabled. (ab) instead of \(ab\) will match "ab".) https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/postgresql/index.html can support the mere BRE but it is a bit slow and can't be easily incorporated into the Scheme code (I am learning SICP and SDF so I didn't check Http implementation in Scheme. The above book uses shell to run grep). I use expression a\+c and input abc to test with option b enabled. It shows "regex_matches()" being "(none)".
Then Is there one regex tool following exactly BRE?

The question is less about "which tool" and more about "which library". GNU implementations have always tended to be "convenient" so their regex library lets you use certain ERE and even PCRE-like regular expressions when Posix says only BRE should be allowed. I'm assuming you're on one of these systems?

GNU grep doesn't support + in a BRE. Example echo abbc | grep 'ab+c' returns nothing. This is with grep --version as grep (GNU grep) 3.11

... but when you say your grep supports + in BRE mode (without -E), you mean it supports \+, right? Are you looking for a system where BRE tools don't support \+ and other GNU-isms?

The regular expression library on OpenBSD does not support \+ in BREs (while that on macOS does, and therefore presumably also on FreeBSD). Would installing OpenBSD in a VM solve your issue?

@Kusalananda I updated my post to reflect these points. 1. Sorry for not saying my OS info. 2. Here I assume + means \+ same as what BRE requires for Special Characters. 3. "installing OpenBSD in a VM" can solve my problem. But it is a bit convenient. Since you says "GNU implementations have always tended to be "convenient"", then I tried website https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/postgresql/index.html.

the new version of the standard appears to say "it is implementation-defined whether "?", "+", and "|" each match the literal character '?', '+', or '|', respectively, or behave as described for the ERE special characters '?', '+', and '|', respectively", so I guess on this part GNU isn't even in the undefined territory any more. Doesn't apply to \s and friends, though.

Even with the old version of the standard, since \+ is undefined, I'd say that it's up to the user (you) to not provide regexes that result in undefined regexes to the tool, and not the tool's job to respond in any particular fashion to such regexes. (So grep exactly follows BRE here, AFAIAC, when given a BRE regex whose behaviour is actually defined by POSIX)

@ilkkachu I followed the reference in the SDF book published in 2021. More specifically, the POSIX specification seems to have no \s although https://regex101.com/ supports it which implies many programming languages supports it. POSIX supports [:space:] https://stackoverflow.com/a/26397083/21294350.

@muru "it's up to the user (you) to not provide regexes that result in undefined regexes": Yes. Maybe you are arguing about my test of a\+c, that's one demo to check whether regex engine is BRE. Sorry for possible lackness of rigorousness.

Have you tried  setting POSIXLY_CORRECT?

@An5Drama "that's one demo to check whether regex engine is BRE" ... that demo doesn't check anything with a BRE, since it is undefined. This post doesn't show any evidence that grep doesn't actually comply with the POSIX BRE specs.

@muru Sorry for my phrasing problems. As your 1st comment and Ed Morton's answer "tools can define \s as meaning the same as [[:space:]] to that tool and still conform to the POSIX standard" say, whether \+ is supported someway (throwing error or other ways) here doesn't influence whether it complies to BRE. I will edit my question to say more clearly.

@EdMorton Sorry. I have done that after reading your recommendation.

POSIX defines some characters, known as metacharacters or "special characters", which have non-literal meanings when used in a regexp, e.g. . matches any character. POSIX also defines what happens when you put a backslash \ before such a metacharacter, i.e. it becomes literal so \. matches a literal . character.
Characters that are not such metachars, e.g. s (or + in a BRE), are known as "ordinary characters". What POSIX says about ordinary characters is this (emphasis mine):

9.3.2 BRE Ordinary Characters
An ordinary character is a BRE that matches itself: any character in
the supported character set, except for the BRE special characters
listed in BRE Special Characters.
The interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by an unescaped
 ( '\' ) is undefined, except for:

The characters ')', '(', '{', and '}'
The digits 1 to 9 inclusive (see BREs Matching Multiple Characters)
A character inside a bracket expression


i.e. it specifically does NOT define what happens when you put a \ in front of an ordinary character (except the few mentioned above) which is why tools can define \s as meaning the same as [[:space:]] to that tool and still conform to the POSIX standard since any tool can do whatever it likes given input such that POSIX doesn't define how to handle that input.
Regarding:

Is there one regex tool following exactly BRE?

Most (all?) grep and sed implementations do by default, but a tool that ONLY implements the behaviors defined by POSIX, as I think you're hoping for, simply cannot exist because POSIX deliberately doesn't define everything (POSIX describes the common functionality that most tools have in most situations, it doesn't dictate how all tools must behave in all situations) and so whoever is implementing any version of any tool has to make their own decision on what to do when that tool encounters some input whose handling is not defined by POSIX - implement some functionality they think will be useful, treat it as literal characters, print a warning message, erase all of your files, corrupt your hard drive, or anything else as they see fit. As long as they implement the functionality that IS defined by POSIX then that tool is POSIX compliant regardless of what it does in the undefined cases.
Consider there's some standard for cars that says "when the driver turns the steering wheel to the right, the car turns right". A car manufacturer would be expected to conform to that requirement. The standard probably doesn't define what happens if you pull the steering wheel towards you so if Nissan decides that if you do that in a 2015 Maxima then the car takes off and starts flying or compresses itself into a small cube, that's still compliant with the standard. Similarly POSIX defines what ., s, and \. means but POSIX doesn't define what \s means and so GNU can define \s to be equivalent to [[:space:]] or whatever they like and still be POSIX compliant.
So, if you want a regexp that behaves the same in all versions of a tool such as grep in the ways defined by POSIX, just don't write a regexp that relies on behavior that's undefined by POSIX. That includes not writing \+ in a BRE and not writing \s in a BRE or ERE, and then whatever grep you're using will conform to the applicable POSIX standard when processing that regexp.
POSIX regexps, BREs and EREs, are defined in the POSIX standard, not in the man page for any given tool and definitely not at regex101.com which AFAIK doesn't have an option for handling POSIX BREs or EREs.
Regarding the suggestion in the comments to set POSIXLY_CORRECT: POSIXLY_CORRECT only applies to GNU tools so it wouldn't help with BSD, etc. tools, and what it does varies on a per-tool basis even within GNU, e.g. in GNU awk with POSIXLY_CORRECT set it'll report \s as undefined behavior and treat it as just a literal s in a regexp while in GNU grep it'll treat \s (and \+) the same way whether POSIXLY_CORRECT is set or not. For example:
$ echo 'a b' | gawk '/a\sb/'
a b

$ echo 'a b' | grep 'a\sb'
a b

$ echo 'a b' | POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 gawk '/a\sb/'
gawk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence `\s' is not a known regexp operator

$ echo 'a b' | POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 grep 'a\sb'
a b


$ echo 'asb' | gawk '/a\sb/'
$

$ echo 'asb' | grep 'a\sb'
$

$ echo 'asb' | POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 gawk '/a\sb/'
gawk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence `\s' is not a known regexp operator
asb

$ echo 'asb' | POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 grep 'a\sb'
$


POSIXLY_CORRECT seems to mostly concern the handling of command line arguments in GNU grep (reordering, illegal option handling, etc.), not the program's matching-related features.
